# Nib-created view retaining file's owner prevents deallocation of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have a view controller that I want to be released (and then possibly reallocated later in the application).  The problem is that its view seems to hold a strong reference to it as shown in the stack trace below.  Does the view need to be deallocated before the view controller?  If so, how can I do this?  Thanks for the help :)

Code:

```
- (void)setCurrentCourse:(Course *)newCourse
{
    ... Reference count management ...

    // area of concern
    if (currentCourse == nil) {

        [self.rvc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.rvc release];
        // HERE I want rvc to be deallocated, but the retainCount is one.
    } else {
        // This is where I allocate the rvc instance
        self.rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];
        [self.view addSubview:self.rvc.view];
    }
}
```

Backtrace from overriden -(id)retain;

```
#0  -[RootViewController retain] (self=0x1bb610, _cmd=0x349b6814) at RootViewController.m:609
#1  0x340b1cdc in CFRetain ()
#2  0x341620c0 in __CFBasicHashStandardRetainValue ()
#3  0x34163440 in __CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#4  0x340b1ff8 in CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#5  0x340b6162 in CFSetAddValue ()
#6  0x340c3012 in -[__NSCFSet addObject:] ()
#7  0x348cb70c in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] ()
#8  0x348cce08 in -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] ()
#9  0x348465e8 in -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] ()
#10 0x34813fa4 in -[UIViewController loadView] ()
#11 0x346f8ebe in -[UIViewController view] ()
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `rvc` is a retain property, **you have a leak**. That's why the controller is not getting `dealloc`ated. When you create the view controller you are **over-retaining** it:

```
self.rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:...];
```

`alloc` returns a retained object (+1). Then, the property setter also retains the object (+2). Later, when you release (-1) the object, you end up with a +1.

To solve this, either use a temporary variable or `autorelease`:

```
self.rvc = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:...] autorelease];
```

---

Another concern is the way you release the object that your property is holding to:

```
[self.rvc release];
```

After this statement, you have relinquished ownership of the object and nothing guarantees you that the object will be valid in the future but your property is still holding a pointer to it. In other words, you have a potential dangling reference. So, nil out the property as you release it with this single statement (this will release the old object):

```
self.rvc = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks.  So...should I rename my question? :D

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think you should rename your question since it reflects your original thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[self.rvc release];` to `[rvc release];`:

```
- (void)setCurrentCourse:(Course *)newCourse {
    // area of concern
    if (currentCourse == nil) {
        [self.rvc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [rvc release];
        // HERE I want rvc to be deallocated, but the retainCount is one.
    } else {
        // This is where I allocate the rvc instance
        rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];
        [self.view addSubview:self.rvc.view];
    }
}
```

or use `self.rvc = nil;` because when you set nil as an instance variable, the setter just retains nil (which does nothing) and releases the old value.

And use

`rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];`

instead of

`self.rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My issue persists.  What's the problem with `[self.rvc release]`?

Comment: Try changing `self.rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];` to `rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] courseSelectionController:self];` also.

Comment: self. calls the auto generated setter code, which retains whatever is passed, so alloc'ing something, then sending it to self.property gives it a retain count of 2, instead of 1 like you want.  See albertamg's answer for a more detailed explanation.